# client side control in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to create PeopleEditor Control on Client side using Javascript and HTML. Without using .aspx Page?

OR

Can we create client side people picker control in PeopleEditor 2010?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 1):

PeoplePicker makes direct queries to Active Directory, so I think it is impossible to do on a client side.

But you can use Sharepoint users as data source: 
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Users%20and%20Groups&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices

or profiles:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserProfileService&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices